# Pyautogui for different resolution

Tags: python, coordinates, pyautogui

I have done an automation using python by importing pyautogui module (using coordinates). It is working fine. Now, I am running the same code on my Laptop. It is not working as expected due to change in coordinates. I don't want to change the coordinates according to my Laptop resolution. I need to generalize the code. So that it should work in any system. Please help me. Thanks in advance